# Android) Get WeChat login information

Tags: android, authentication, wechat

I succeeded, Creating a Facebook App to get the login data. so, I want to create an app to get the login data of the next wechat.
But it was less information, and a lot different.
So I want to ask you a few questions.

1. It will provide the login button like Facebook?
2. It is available in Android Studio to easily add code to Gradle?
3. Is there a site where you can view basic information on how to receive a login WeChat to Android Studio?

I apologize for the difficult questions.
Please answer a lot or a little.
Thanks.

Comment: please refer this wechat document : http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/download

Comment: I've already seen wechat developers
But I could not find how to drive the sdk came there from android studio.